# Jquery attr() not working inside click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying for 3 days figure out why the attr() isn't working inside functions in Jquery. It may look like the question has already been answered but none of them is working for me.

I'm trying to change the `data-text` atribute from a tweet button to tweet the current text.

Here is my code:

```
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", "Hello World"); //Working

$("#change").on("click", function() {
    $(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", "Hello Universe"); // Not working
});
```

Example in Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ooneskbe/

Comment: Maybe `cilck` event didn't  fired.

Comment: This has nothing to do with attr in functions, it just doesn't work because the twitter code replaces your element with a new one and stores your `data-text` somewhere else.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ooneskbe/1/ but the button is inserted in an iFrame and takes the attribute value on pageload

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ooneskbe/2/ What are you expecting this to do exactly?

Comment: @charlietfl I need to generate a random quote and be able to share on twitter. It's a little application from Free Code Camp: codepen.io/sadraque/full/kkrypA

As all of you pointed, the twitter scripts is changing the structure of the button, I'm trying figuring out something else to implementing this function. Thank you all.

Comment: need to be using the twitter api for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not represent the whole picture. The reason why this is not working, is because of this script that you include:

```
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This script changes your HTML. If the script is not included, the generated HTML of a button is

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
```

However, as soon as this script is loaded and executed, your HTML becomes

```
<a class="btn" id="b" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F_display%2F&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&amp;tw_p=tweetbutton&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F_display%2F">
    <i></i>
    <span class="label" id="l">Tweet</span>
</a>
```

You can see that the new HTML does not have a class `twitter-share-button`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the data attribute, but you need to think of some other way to do this.

Comment: I'm trying to tweet a random generated quote, it works fine when the page is first loaded but it not work after a click a button to change that quote.

Comment: I need to generate a random quote and be able to share on twitter.
It's a little application from Free Code Camp: https://codepen.io/sadraque/full/kkrypA

Comment: @SadraqueSantos It works the first time the page is loaded, because the Twitter widget script is not executed yet, therefore you are able to find element by class `twitter-share-button`. After the script executes this class does not exist anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm trying to make the share button the wrong way.
I'm figuring out something else. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", "Hello World");
var dataObj = $(".twitter-share-button").data();
$("#change").on("click", function() {
    dataObj.text = "Hello Universe";
    $(".twitter-share-button").data(dataObj);
});
```

try it : https://jsfiddle.net/667f171z/1/

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".